# Howto do this in Dartt $current_segment =~ s/([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)/$1 punto $2/g;

Tags: regex, dart, matching

I do appreciate if anyone could help me with this seemingly easy question:

`$someText =~ s/([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)/$1 : $2/g;`

This perl statement  finds all patterns of the form  www.xyz and changes them to www:xyz.
I need an equivalent code in Dart;  I am new to Dart.
Thanks,
Bid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it something like this:

```dart
RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)');

void main() {
  String someText = 'www.xyz';
  someText = someText.replaceAllMapped(regExp, (m) => '${m[1]}:${m[2]}');
  print(someText); // www:xyz
}
```

I have put the `RegExp` outside `main` to illustrate it is best to keep this object around, instead of recreating the `RegExp` for every usage, since it can be expensive, in runtime, depending of how it is used.

Comment: Or, `someText = someText.replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\.(?=[a-zA-Z])'), ':');`.

Comment: It wont work if you  have a period at the end of your phrase.  The first solution is what I was looking for as it enables me to have access to positional arguments.  Perhaps I did not phrase my question well but 
user avatar
julemand101 did understand the purpose of the question.  And many thanks

Comment: @Bid Please mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. If you can't yet accept it, please describe what is missing so I can add it to the solution.